# How find this this distance $d_{1}d_{2}=b^2$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

On the plane we have two points $A(\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0),B(-\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0)$ with $a>b>0$ and the line $L$, of which the equation is given as:$$\dfrac{x\cos{\theta}}{a}+\dfrac{y\sin{\theta}}{b}=1$$

Define $d_{1}$ to be the distance between the straight line $L$ and point $A$ and $d_{2}$ to be the distance between the straight line $L$ and point $B$. Find the value  $$d_{1}\cdot d_{2}$$

My attempt:

Since 
$$d_{1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\cos{\theta}}{a}-1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2{\theta}}{b^2}}}$$
and 
$$d_{2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\cos{\theta}}{a}-1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2{\theta}}{b^2}}}$$
therefore
$$d_{1}d_{2}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}\cos^2{\theta}}{\dfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2{\theta}}{b^2}}=\frac{\sin^2{\theta}+\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}\cos^2{\theta}}{\dfrac{b^2\cos^2{\theta}+a^2\sin^2{\theta}}{a^2b^2}}=b^2$$

I think this is very ugly. Can someone do this via another method? Thank you.

Comment: Can you draw a picture so that we can grab the meaning of your question more easily?

Answer (score 3):

The basic process won't get much better than you have, but the presentation can be made a little cleaner with a couple of minor adjustments to avoid having to write so many radicals and fractions:

Define $c := \sqrt{a^2-b^2}$, so that $A = (c,0)$ and $B=(-c,0)$, and write the equation of $L$ as $$x b \cos\theta + y a \sin\theta = a b$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
d_1 &= \frac{b\;|c\cos\theta-a|}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta}} = \frac{b\;\left( a - c\cos\theta\right)}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta}} \quad \text{since}\quad c\cos\theta \leq c \leq a\\[6pt] 
d_2 &= \frac{b\;\left( a + c\cos\theta\right)}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta}}
\end{align}$$
Then
$$d_1 d_2 = \frac{b^2\;\left( a^2 - c^2\cos^2\theta \right)}{a^2\sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta}$$

Now, observe that
$$a^2 - c^2\cos^2\theta \;\;=\;\; a^2 - (a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta \;\;=\;\; a^2 \sin^2\theta + b^2\cos^2\theta$$
so that
$$d_1 d_2 = b^2$$

Comment: Nice,+1.I think this line $\dfrac{x\sin{\theta}}{a}+\dfrac{y\cos{\theta}}{b}=1$ is $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ at the point $(a\cos{\theta},b\sin{\theta})$ tangent,maybe this have good methods?

Comment: @chinamath: It's not clear what "good methods" might apply here. You mention "tangent" in your comment, but your original question doesn't mention any *curves* that might admit tangents. (I took your question to be about simplifying some algebra.) Perhaps you could describe the geometric problem that your equations are meant to solve.